# IText7 How to decode field's default appearance int Font object and its properties

Tags: pdf, itext7

I have an `AcroForm` with some fields, and I need to fetch font information for one of fields. I know that I must use

`(PdfFormField)field.getDefaultAppearance()`

but this results in string like

```
/Helv 12 Tf 0.25 0.25 0.25 rg`
```

Is there a simple way to parse that string into `PdfFont` object?

It is obvoious that I can parse that by hand from given string, but I suspect that IText have some utils tha will do that for me isnt' it?

Besides `/Helv` is only "reference" or something like that, obviously pointinc to `Helvetica` but what if I would have some sort of custom fonts?

Thanks!

Comment: Concerning **Helv** etc: usually font names in the associated font resources dictionary are mapped to font definitions. The font names in **D**efault**A**ppearances sometimes are not, though, cf. the section *Using /Helv, /HeBo, ...* in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30248927/1729265).

Answer (score 1):

If you want the font used in the formfield, you can use the `PdfFormField#getFont()` method, this will return the `PdfFont` object used direcly. To set a custom font, use `PdfFormField#setFont(PdfFont font)`, this will also recreate the appearance of the form field. Use `PdfFormField#setFontSize(float fontsize)` to set the size of the text inside the field. Use `PdfFormField#setClor(..)` to set the text color.

The information you get from the getDefaultAppearance() is written in pdf syntax and can be parsed as follows:

```
`/Helv 12 Tf 0.25 0.25 0.25 rg`
```

The `font size Tf` instructions sets the *font(subset)* and *size* for the text instructions that follows. Fonts are referred using the name they are inserted into the pdf. In this case /Helv, which will probably point to (a subset) of Helvetica. It doesn't have to be helvetica however, some joker could've inserted Comic Sans and named it /Helv. 12 is the font size.

The `x y z rg` method sets the colour of the font using RGB values, with *x, y* and *z* relative intensity values in the interval [0.0,1.0].