# How to get font info in the acroforms?

Tags: pdf, itext, itext7

I have the following pdf structure key in the acroform fields:

```
DA: /Helv 12 Tf 0 g
```

I suppose the `DA` key is the font description but I can't understand what does it means that value `/Helv 12 Tf 0 g`.
Can anyone help to decode it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DA is the default appearance.

- `/Helv 12` is for the font family and the font size
- `Tf` is the set text font and size operator
- `g` is the grey level operator and 0 means it's just black.

So all in all it's a Helvetica type font, size 12 and black.

Comment: can you give me more information about it? Where can I read about it? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You can check out the PDF reference: https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf - probably there are also documents dedicated to AcroForms but I don't know them.

Comment: Concerning the font name you should additionally read the section "Using /Helv, /HeBo, ..." from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30248927/1729265). If you have to understand PDF forms from the wild, knowing this deviation of Adobe Readers from the specification might help.